# Is there a way to put these two lines of code in one line

Tags: python

I would like to make my code as small as possible and I wanted to know if I could shorten the code into just one line

```
i = ("***** Cafe Menu *****")

print("*"*len(i)+"\n"+i+"\n"+"*"*len(i))
```

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: I have to ask why you want to do this.  When I worked at a major SW company, the dev manager had this plaque on the wall.  "Debugging code is twice as hard as writing it.  Therefor if you write code as cleverly as possible, you are by definition not smart enough to debug it."  Favor readability and maintainability over cleverness.

Comment: can you show us what output you are expecting

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve in the code.

Comment: If you're intent on this, here's one way to do it without assignment expressions: https://onelinepy.herokuapp.com/

Comment: What is an issue ?

Comment: The question in the title (combining two lines of code) is different than the goal stated in the body (making the code as small as possible). So what *is* your question exactly? Do you want the shortest possible code size? If so, this is called Code Golf, and is off-topic for Stack Overflow, but can be asked on [codegolf.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the *question*:

```
print((lambda x: "\n".join(("*" * len(x), x, "*" * len(x))))("***** Cafe Menu *****"))
```

But it's just much clearer to write this:

```
def fancy(s):
    stars = "*" * len(s)
    return "\n".join((stars, s, stars))

print(fancy("***** Cafe Menu *****"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print("*"*len(("***** Cafe Menu *****"))+"\n"+("***** Cafe Menu *****")+"\n"+"*"*len(("***** Cafe Menu *****")))
```

This is how you could do it; however, this is much messier and longer, so I woudl strongly advise using what you have written in your question with defining a varibale because it is repreated several times.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it up like:
`print("*"*len('***** Cafe Menu *****')+"\n"+'***** Cafe Menu *****'+"\n"+"*"*len('***** Cafe Menu *****'))`

Answer (score 0):

A semicolon will join them as one line.

As from Py3.8, Using the new [walrus operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/), `:=`

```
print(f"{'*'*(l:=len(i:='***** Cafe Menu *****'))}\n{i}\n{'*'*l}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Py 3.6+ using f-string:

```
i = ("***** Cafe Menu *****"); print(f'{"*"*len(i)}\n{i}\n{"*"*len(i)}')
```